# Ubuntu 22.04 no desktop icons, selection, right click menu options

Tags: 22.04

It used to work until yesterday at least, and I think it happened after installing and running a virtual machine through Virtualbox. Pretty much the whole desktop is idle and unusable. I don't mind this, as I don't usually use the desktop to store files or folders on it, but I am curious what I did and how it can be reversed or intentionally brought to this state.

At some point icons disappeared, can't be added, I can't left click + hold to select anything, and the right click menu doesn't give me anything but the 3 options seen on the screenshot. The right click menu works fine when I am in folders though.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I also have the same issue. In my case reinstalling the ubuntu desktop worked.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

After running this, restart the system.

Comment: After installing the `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` you might need to enable the extensions from the extension manager.
If you cannot see the desktop icons option in the list, try installing `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng` using the command `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng` and enabling it from the extensions.

Comment: Or use `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop-minimal` if you have installed minimal version.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was probably related to the `fuse` package that I have installed manually to allow a third party app to work (kDrive from Infomaniak). Reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` replaced `fuse` with `fuse3` and now all is working. After a reboot all my Desktop icons are here.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. You may follow this:

Using synaptic package manager you can search whether there is ubuntu-desktop package in your system.

You can install that package using the same app (Synaptic). Install it.

Then restart the system. Everything will be OK.

......... I could fix the problem this way.

Answer (score 1):

#### I faced the same issue and I just ran the below command:

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

#### This command will refresh your desktop UI service. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting didn't fix this, but shutting the pc off, and then on again did fix it...